# JFreeChart with time range axis

Tags: java, jfreechart, categories, bar-chart

Have set with data, where object represent service with min time, max time, avg time and name of service.
Need to show this set by category bar chart, where category is name of service.
But main problem in: How to make range axis in this chart to show time like (... hourse ... min)?

Comment: Range axis as well as value axis shows the data that you put there. So if you want to show time, you have to put there time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix DateAxis (a specialization of ValueAxis) with CategoryAxis. If you want to do something like

[image]

Your only choice is to define your parent category with the name of the category and then add subcategories with customized labels in order to show formatted dates or whatever you want.

If you want to write dates use this ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format the string

See the example here:

https://code.google.com/p/swing-ui-hxzon/source/browse/trunk/jfreechart/org/jfree/chart/demo/SubCategoryAxisDemo1.java?spec=svn67&r=67

Comment: Need category. On x-axis need category "Service 1", where 3 bar(min time, max time and avg time), and so on.

Comment: @disable1992 I think i'm not understanding exactly what do you want, if were possible do a quick mock up please.

You cannot mix CategoryAxis, ValueAxis. So if you need categories maybe your best choice will be to use SubCategoryAxis inside a CategoryAxis and make your own labels by formatting the date.

It will look like this http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/424691okJFreeChart.gif 

There is an example here https://code.google.com/p/swing-ui-hxzon/source/browse/trunk/jfreechart/org/jfree/chart/demo/SubCategoryAxisDemo1.java?spec=svn67&r=67

Comment: Yes, something like this I need, with time value axis.

Comment: thx! But for date (in long variable) I must re-implement some class for my format?

Comment: @disable1992 No, just write whatever you want as label. See my changes

Comment: This i know. But how do this stuff on axis? Value (in my case time) in long type, and need show it on axis. For example, for first bar in category value contain some long value==5 hours 35 minutes. Find no full solution: `DateAxis rangeAxis = new DateAxis();
        RelativeDateFormat rdf = new RelativeDateFormat();
        rdf.setShowZeroDays(false);
        rdf.setSecondFormatter(new DecimalFormat("00"));
        rangeAxis.setDateFormatOverride(rdf);
        plot.setRangeAxis(rangeAxis);`

Comment: Sadly i think that there is no global solution as you can't cast CategoryAxis with ValueAxis.

Answer (score 0):

Use classes from **org.jfree.data.time** package .
Find example [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/TimeSeriesChartDemo1.html)